# Why is my ps4 disabling my internet?

Tags: router, internet, gaming

So I'm having an issue that when my PS4 is up and running, I am unable to access the internet on any of the computers on my home network.

This problem just started occuring when I was experimenting with the share functionality and I have 3 videos in the upload queue. Whenever the PS4 is running, the uploads progress, albeit slowly (about 0.1 mbps) but I'm not able to play any games on PSN or access the internet.

It was working flawlessly before the videos were added to the upload queue. I will update with whether or not it works correctly once the uploads are finished. But, any guesses as to what is going on here?

Extra information: I was suspicious that there might have been a problem with the router assignment of ips in my network but the router is set to automatic dhcp mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So while mdpc very thoroughly explained why the problem occurred, I thought id share what I had to do to fix it.

I logged into my router under the QOS settings and set a limit on the upstream to 75% of my ISP's quoted speed. My internet package is only 15/1, so I set the limit for my ps4's mac address to 750kbps.

Be aware though, the PS4 hogs every last bit of that 750 kbps, so you might easily still hit problems if you are doing any heavy uploading on another device on your network at the same time. From what I've seen with my connection, the PS4 simply bullies your connection past what it can handle. By limiting the connection not only are my other devices able to connect to the internet again, but the upload speed of the videos on the PS4 has greatly improved to about what it should be (700-750kpbs on my connection.) It seems like the PS4's hogging was also causing some sort of overload effect making it so that even the PS4 was having connection issues.

Answer (score 1):

Many home ISP providers, like the one I use, severely limit UPLOAD speed eventhough download speed is excellent.  What this means is that if something is taking up the entire upload bandwidth then all the computers on your connection suffer because of this.

I have had this happen using cloud backup software, while it was running for awhile on one computer, my other computers and wireless access on my home ISP connection had problems in using the internet.  There was no way to throttle back on its use of uplink bandwidth.

The essential problem here are that nearly all web transactions require two way communications, for instance the data that comes from the provider to your computer via a browser must be ACK'd requiring uplink traffic.  If your application is hogging the uplink bandwidth, these ACKs and programs requiring two way communications are SEVERELY hampered.

Comment: One thing... I don't have this issue uploading from my computer instead of the ps4. The ps4 seems to solidly dominate the upload stream and literally not allow any other data through. Is this really the way it is supposed to operate?